# What is the point of observer pattern in flutter TextField Widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, observer-pattern

I am tasked with making a page where upon inputting some text into a TextField, i need to retrieve a list of posts which i get using http request.

And my team lead told me that i should use an observer pattern, which was unkown to me before. I know what it does now, after he explained it to me 3 times.

But i can't wrap my head around why would i use it instead of onChanged attribute in TextField widget, which already listens to any changes made to the TextField, and sends the text to entity, which i then use to send my http request.

Explain it to me in more simpler terms with simple analogies, so I can understand it once and for all. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: It's not that I think it's bad, my team lead says that it's the best way complete this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try. When you send http request on text change using `onChanged` there are too much requests can be potentially sent at short period of time. Let's suppose user types in a long word, then deletes some symbols because of typo, then types it again. Too much http requests will be send – on every change, right? And what if you have a lot of users?

To escape unnecessary network load you need to [debounce](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/debounce.html) text field changes. Observer pattern and [rxDart](https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart) is the option to do it. Here is an example:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

class SomeWidgetState extends State<SomeWidget> {
  final textStreamController = StreamController<String>();
  Stream<String> get textStream => textStreamController.stream;
  StreamSubscription textStreamSubscription;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // HERE is how to use debounce
    textStreamSubscription =
        textStream.debounceTime(Duration(seconds: 1)).listen(sendRequest);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    textStreamController.close();
    textStreamSubscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void sendRequest(String text) {
    // Here you can send http request
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(onChanged: textStreamController.add);
  }
}
```

I guess your team leader wants to take this approach.

Comment: actually you should not use `listen` - `sendRequest` should be used with `Stream.asyncMap` (or similar "mapping" method) so it creates a new "mapped" `Stream` that can be directly used as an input for `StreamBuilder`

Comment: @pskink we don't need StreamBuilder here, are you sure asyncMap is required?
By the way, I forgot to save reference to StreamSubscription and cancel it onDispose. Just edited my post

Comment: *"I am tasked with making a page where upon inputting some text into a TextField, i need to retrieve a list of posts which i get using http request."* - so OP wants a "live" search and somehow "a list of posts" needs to be shown - this is a job for `StreamBuilder` - its input is `textStream.debounceTime(Duration(seconds: 1)).asyncMap(sendRequest);`

Comment: Oh, I understand. @pskink Good notice, thanks.

Comment: your welcome, btw even better is `switchMap` from `rxdart`